# Is there a workaround for overlaying transparent images from resources?

Tags: c#, image

Right now I have a form with a `PictureBox` on the form.  I'm using two partially transparent images and trying to put one on top of the other.

- *sideMenuWide* = rounded rectangle with transparent background (.png) [Bottom image]
- *labelPointer* = triangle with transparent background (.png) [Top image]

Here is my approach:

```
// METHOD #1 //
Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\sideMenuWide.png");
Image img2 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\labelPointer.png");
picBox.Image = CombineImages(img1, img2);

// METHOD #2 //
Image imgA = RBS.Properties.Resources.sideMenuWide;
Image imgB = RBS.Properties.Resources.labelPointer;
picBox.Image = CombineImages(imgA, imgB);
```

And the CombineImage function:  (I did not write this function, only modified)

```
public static Bitmap CombineImages(Image imgA, Image imgB)
    {
        //a holder for the result (By default, use the first image as the main size)
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(imgA.Size.Width, imgA.Size.Height);

        //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            //set the resize quality modes to high quality
            graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            //draw the images into the target bitmap
            graphics.DrawImage(imgA, 0, 0, imgA.Width, imgA.Height);
            graphics.DrawImage(imgB, 100, 70, imgB.Width, imgB.Height);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Method #1** DOES work how I want it to, displays imgB perfectly on top of imgA.

**Method #2** however shows imgA just fine but imgB is really faint.

Any ideas on how to overcome this?  I would like to be able to do this using Resources instead of having to pull from a file.

Comment: I think your "new Bitmap" needs to return one with a 32bit palette. I'm not sure that's the default.

Answer (score 0):

If the files work when loaded, but the resources don't, then it sounds like the resx build process or the ResourceManager is doing something undesirable. I'd try embedding the files and reading them directly from a stream rather than relying on the ResourceManager to do it for you.

- In your Solution Explorer, **Add Existing File** to add the file to your project. Get properties on the added file and set it to **Embedded Resource=**. (Don't add it to a resx file)
- In your code, you can now get a stream containing the file's data:

  ```
  Stream instream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
                      GetManifestResourceStream("RBS.labelPointer.png"));
  ```

  *(Hint: The compiler generates an obtuse name for the embedded resource, so after adding the files you can add temporary code to call Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() to get a list of them all and find the file you're interested in)*
- Load your bitmap/image from the stream:

  `Image img2 = new Bitmap(inStream);`

Comment: Thank all of you guys for giving me great places to start! The stream idea worked fantastic!